Book/story from 70s or earlier. US builds a wall. Years later an American leaves and finds the world is better without it
A book or story from the 1970s or earlier. The US builds a wall around itself for protection from the rest of the world - nobody is allowed in or out. Years later an American finds a way to leave and discovers that the rest of the world has been better without the US.

How very topical.

Probably a science fiction story, taking place in 2026-2028 ...

While not main topic of the story/stories, something like this is mentioned in a german book - collection of short stories - called "Who'd have the idea of stealing legs?" (Wer stiehlt schon Unterschenkel), 1977, by german author Gert Prokop, where dystopian United States are isolated from rest of the world by impenetrable force field. Official version is United State built it for its protection, but main protagonist knows/learns it was actually put there by other countries, which are prospering in almost (communist?) utopian way, without contact/involvement of US.

While not an exact match, John Brunner's 'The Wrong End of Time' (1971) has a lot of similarities. I remember most the beginning centered on the extreme border defences of an atrophied america and sleeper agents.
Since it's a John Brunner novel, there are a lot of ideas in there.

Some of Brunner's novels, like Stand on Zanzibar, have a lot of ideas.  However, others, such as The Altar on Asconel, are fairly shallow space opera.
